# Error C2371. typedef struct

Tags: c++, string

```
typedef struct _STRING {
    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    #ifdef MIDL_PASS
        [size_is(MaximumLength), length_is(Length)]
    #endif
    PCHAR Buffer;
} STRING, *PSTRING;
```

```
Error 2 error C2371: PSTRING: redefinition; different basic types
Error 2 error C2371: STRING: redefinition; different basic types
```

Comment: So, what is your question exactly? The error message is relatively clear.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to redefine an [existing type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code (probably in an included header) `USHORT`, `PCHAR`, `STRING`, and `PSTRING` have been defined as type names.

So the compiler reports an error when it sees `STRING` and `PSTRING` being defined a second time.

The reason the compiler says "different basic types" is that defining a type name a second time is NOT an error if you define it as the exact same thing as the first definition.

To remove these errors you can either 1) use different type names so there is no conflict or 2) remove the header that already defined those names outside of your code.